# Clicking on an autocomplete item in jquery mobile triggers the element behind it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to use autocomplete inside of jquery mobile and it is working good however when I start typeing and I decide to select an element that is over another 'IE the button in the jsfiddle' it will trigger the button as well. How do I prevent this? Is this a JQM bug? I had tried inserting the results into a div however it still triggered the button.

http://jsfiddle.net/jostster/XuZBt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, not a bug, just a z-index issue. The autocomplete list is lower on the DOM than the button, so it is on top of it. Not sure why it doesn't show it visibly though. Here's the fiddle with the fix: http://jsfiddle.net/XuZBt/1/

Comment: You rock! It looks like jquery-ui hard codes the z-index of the menu to 1. Would it be better for me to overwrite that in css and set it to 999 so that I don't have to go through each of the elements and set them to 0?

Comment: i would like to just set all input, selects to 0 z-index but it seems it won't allow you too :( any ideas?

Comment: weird... Works on jsfiddle but not on my site. even though I am using !important.

Comment: I had to go and set `.ui-btn-text` zindex to `0` as well in my site.

Comment: Hm, yea that is one issue with this -- having to set the z-index on every element that should be under the list. I'm not sure what might be going on with your site as there could be a lot of other CSS going into play there.

Comment: Oh, I know the fix. You can specify the container the list goes into, using the 'appendTo' option in the autocomplete setup. Then just set that container to a high z-index.

Comment: I am testing the fiddle, but as I type characters there's no "dropdown" giving me the autocomplete. Can't see what I am missing